# Overhead of order by on long

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a project where I have to sort a list of messages. Basically these are messages placed somewhere with gps positions. I have an id field a message field (blob) longitude latitude ownertype and userrating. The point is to sort these messages according to ownertype and userrating. ownertype is a tinyint and userrating is an int. The question is, is it better to just get all the relevant messages joined with the users and then order it in java , or is it better to  do an order by clause in your sql statement.

I forgot to add a couple of things. There are going to be thousands of request a minute but the rows returned could potentially reach a hundred.

Comment: How many rows are you returning, and how many rows total in table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

databases are excellent at sorting and retrieving sets. - let it do that for you.